# SWT/JFace table performance with many columns

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I have a table with approximately 100 columns. Number of rows are not very large, about 300 rows. But it's performance is not very good.

Scrolling (especially horizontal) and adding new rows proceed with visible lags. I do not use `SWT.VIRTUAL` as it's good for cases when there are huge number of rows. I'm aware of alternative table implementations in SWT, but my question is particularly about SWT/JFace implementation. Is there any way to improve performance for table with quite large amount of columns?

Comment: Not sure if you are already aware of http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/?page=6 and https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/xviewer/xviewer.php

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of both of them. NatTable looks great, but it's completely different from SWT table and I have to do a lot of work to migrate to it

Answer (score 0):

As you already stated, `SWT.VIRTUAL` only helps with large number of rows. AFAIK there isn't much you can do to improve handling a large amount of columns.

... other than reducing the amoiunt of columns. Left aside the weak performance, are you sure that 100 columns will lead to a good user experience? Wouldn't it be better to choose a different form of presenting the information?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's something like presence/absence matrix

Comment: @Hexe In that case, wouldn't it be easier to draw something on a canvas?

Comment: As far as I know NatTable draw on canvas. But there are a lot of work to do to move to it. Existing content providers, label providers do not fit.

Comment: @Hexe There may not be a solution using tables that is efficient enough though.